# JQTouch, jquery element html not updating on ipod

Tags: jquery

I am using JQTouch to make s simple shopping cart, those not familiar with JQTouch should know that "pages" are made up of DIVS using the DIV id as fragment identifier within the index page. So you have one big page filled with DIVS that make up sub pages......anyhue. My shopping cart has it's own identifier.

```
 <div id="checkout">
 <div class="toolbar">
 <h1>Checkout</h1>
 <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
 </div>
 <ul id="trolley" class="rounded"><li>Cart Empty</li></ul>
 </div>
```

Once a user finishes ordering they can go to the "checkout" which runs this rather ugly solution.

```
 case "trolley":
 $('#checkout').bind('pageAnimationEnd', function(e, info){
 $("#trolley").html(stripslashes(data.contents))
 });
 break;
```

What im trying to do here is get the json result from a post request (data.contents) and dump it in my trolley after the animation has completed.

This works seamlessly in chrome on a desktop but on a touch it always comes up "cart empty". I have tried to load the div at animation start, I have tried to load the div before animating but no dice. If i leave the cart and go back in again it does work correctly.

I should mention how I call the cart.

```
    <a class="button" id="cart" href="#checkout" onclick="cart('0','trolley')" >$0.00</a>
```

this simply tells the script there is nothing to add but return the trolley contents.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I removed the href from the checkout button and used the following after the DIV had been updated.

```
   jQT.goTo('#checkout', 'slideup');
```